# Transpose & Deduplicate - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I want to extract data from a SQL Server 2019, to be able to present it on a line chart in a report. My data is the number of job offers for a given skill. Basically, I am scraping job boards to be able to estimate how many job offers there are for a given skill in a given time period.

I've written a simple `group by` query that got me the data I wanted:

```
  select sn.Name, csr.CreatedAt, sum(csr.JobOffersCount) as Amount
  from   CompanySkillRegionDemands csr,
         SkillNames sn
  where csr.SkillId = sn.SkillId
  and   sn.Language = 'en'
  group by sn.Name, csr.CreatedAt
  order by CreatedAt
```

With the data looking like:

| Name | CreatedAt | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ASP.NET MVC | 2020-05-13 | 40 |
| Webforms | 2020-05-13 | 2 |
| Microsoft Visio | 2020-05-13 | 6 |
| SAP BI | 2020-05-13 | 1 |

For a long time period. The problem is the duplicate Names and Dates. For each date there is a name, which is correct but it also makes it very difficult to draw an excel chart out of it, after extracting it to a csv.

Instead of the above, I would prefer having a matrix where the dates are on the Y axis and skill names are on X, like so:

|  | .NET | SAP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-13 | 2 | 3 |
| 2020-05-14 | 1 | 5 |

How would I go around it?

Comment: How do you define ".net" and ".sap"?

Comment: Its just the skill name from the data, for example ASP.NET MVC or Java. I have over 300 skills like that and for every date there are 300 skill names.

Comment: Evolve - NO ONE should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation.  Something like this:

```
select csr.CreatedAt,
       sum(case when sn.name like '%.net%' then csr.JobOffersCount end) as cnt_net,
       sum(case when sn.name like '%sap%' then csr.JobOffersCount end) as cnt_sap
from  CompanySkillRegionDemands csr join
      SkillNames sn
      on csr.SkillId = sn.SkillId and   sn.Language = 'en'
group by csr.CreatedAt
order by CreatedAt;
```

I'm not sure what the real logic is for the columns, but it is something like what is here.

Comment: I am afraid that won't work, I have over 300 skills like that so I would have to put all 300 in the select clause

Comment: Each record contains the amount of job offers there were, which contained a given skill for a given day. For example: There were 10 job offers that contained the word java on 2021-01-01